# ASP.NET Core SelectList not found in one controller

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, selectlist

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app. My IDE is VS Code and I am using Windows 10.

The `SelectList` can work in one controller but not be found in other controller.

Both controllers are `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`.

How strange it is... could anyone give me a hand?

Comment: Please share code and exact error you are facing

Comment: From your description, I understand that the Select list works in one controller and does not work in another one. To check the issue, could you please share the sample code of your Controller and View for working and working scenarios? It could give some hints for the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

for SelectList of net core you have to use

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
```